# Mostrar/Esconder div por Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

O que quero fazer é bem simples, só que nao está indo.

**HTML**

```
      <select name="id_tipo_contacto" id="id_tipo_contacto">
          <option value="empresa">Alugar Filmes/Séries</option>
          <option value="casamento">Vender Filmes/Séries</option>
      </select>
      <div id="empresa" class="formulario"><h2 style="    color: #21BF16;
      font-weight: bolder;">R$07,99 Por dia.</h2></div>
      <div id="casamento" class="formulario" style="display:none;">R$70,00.</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
  <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
      $j("#id_tipo_contacto").on('change', function(){
          $j(".formulario").hide();
          $j('#' + this.value).show();
});
  </script>
```

Comment: Igor, o teu código funciona: https://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/srpesr8m/ talvez tenhas o script antes do HTML? coloca no final da página.

Comment: Poderia detalhar o objetivo do código e o que não funciona?

Comment: Ta no final de tudo, pode ser a versao do jQuery?

Comment: Crie um exemplo que reproduza o erro (possamos executar diretamente) o problema usando o JSFIDDLE. Da forma que está não tem como sabermos aonde esta a falha.

Comment: Gostaria de simplesmente apresentar os valores de acordo com a opção selecionada. Já coloquei ele embaixo de todo html, já coloquei fora do body, dentro e nada.

Comment: Ele não apresenta nenhum erro no console, simplesmente não funciona.

Comment: O que não funciona?

Comment: Ele não exibe nem esconde os valores..

Comment: Vou mandar o link do meu arquivo inteiro, sem css nem nada, só para voce ver https://jsfiddle.net/cL629s9j/

Comment: @IgorRinke não podes usar `<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">` com script lá dentro... tens de ter 1 tag para caggerar o jQuery `<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>` e outra para ter o JavaScript dentro: `<script>....etc....</script>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
<!--
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
      $j("#id_tipo_contacto").on('change', function(){
          $j(".formulario").hide();
          $j('#' + this.value).show();
});
});
//-->
</script>

  <select name="id_tipo_contacto" id="id_tipo_contacto">
      <option value="empresa">Alugar Filmes/Séries</option>
      <option value="casamento">Vender Filmes/Séries</option>
  </select>
  <div id="empresa" class="formulario"><h2 style="    color: #21BF16;
  font-weight: bolder;">R$07,99 Por dia.</h2></div>
  <div id="casamento" class="formulario" style="display:none;">R$70,00.</div>
```

Comment: Nas apresentações ele funciona, igual aos outros, mas no meu arquivo não.

Comment: @IgorRinke algo errado na sua publicação, editei a resposta e é dessa forma que vc deve publicar no seu arquivo

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado, acho que era por estar abaixo o código

Comment: exato, quando nós fazemos para executar ele inverte a ordem